# Value of $\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My problem is from Israel Gelfand's Trigonometry textbook.

*Page 48. Exercise 8:* b) If $\tan\alpha=r$, write an expression in terms of $r$ that represents the value of $\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$.

*The attempt at a solution:*

Well I solved a) which was similar, question was: a) If $\tan\alpha=2/5$, find the numerical value of $\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$. Solution was this, since $\tan\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=\frac{2}{5}$, then $\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha=5^2-2^2=21$. b) part is more general version of a) I guess, but I can't seem to find identity that would allow me to solve it. I would appreciate some hints, thank you in advance.

Comment: $\frac ab=\frac cd$ does not mean that $a=c$ and $b=d$ !!

Comment: So my solution to a) is not correct?

Comment: @GeorgeDirac No, because $\cos\alpha$ can not exceed 1.

Comment: yeah that's true of course, looks like I have to redo it, thank you @Yves Daoust for noticing my mistake.

Comment: Well, the numerical value would be $21/29=0.724$.

Comment: NOTE: It will also be equal to $cos2\alpha$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Two Hints:**

$$\cos^2 x = \frac{\cos^2x}{1}=\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}=\frac{1}{\tan^2 x+1}$$
And:
$$\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x +(\cos^2x +\sin^2x)-1=2\cos^2x-1$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now. Answer would be $\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2}$.

Comment: @GeorgeDirac - yes it would :)

Answer (score 8):

$$\cos^2⁡x-\sin^2x=\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}.$$

Comment: Using Mathjax on this site is not only preferred, but demanded.

Comment: Very elegant and economical!

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha=2\cos^2\alpha-1$$
and by 
$$\cos^2\alpha=\frac1{1+\tan^2\alpha}$$
we find

$$\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha=\frac2{1+r^2}-1=\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$\sin \alpha=\pm\frac{\tan \alpha}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 \alpha}}\!$$
and
$$\cos \alpha=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 \alpha}}\!$$
then
$$\sin^2 \alpha=\frac{\tan^2 \alpha}{1 + \tan^2 \alpha}=\frac{r^2}{1 + r^2}\!$$
and
$$\cos^2 \alpha=\frac{1}{1 + \tan^2 \alpha}\!=\frac{1}{1 + r^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

My Approach:

$\tan \alpha=r$

$\implies \tan^2 \alpha=r^2$

$\implies \large \frac{\sin^2 \alpha}{\cos^2 \alpha}=r^2$

Apply [Componendo and Dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo)

$\implies \large \frac{\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \alpha}{\sin^2 \alpha-\cos^2 \alpha}=\large \frac{r^2+1}{r^2-1}$

$\implies \large \frac{1}{\sin^2 \alpha - \cos ^2 \alpha}=\large \frac{r^2+1}{r^2-1}$

$\implies {\sin^2 \alpha - \cos ^2 \alpha}=\large \frac{r^2-1}{r^2+1}$

Multiply both sides by -1

$\implies {\cos ^2 \alpha-\sin^2 \alpha}=\large \frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2}$

Answer (score 2):

You start from $r=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$ and must evaluate $\cos^2\alpha-{\sin^2\alpha}$.

This should push you to set $c=\cos^2\alpha, s=\sin^2\alpha$, use $$c+s=1$$
and rewrite the first relation as
$$r^2c-s=0.$$
Solve this linear system for $c$ and $s$:
$$(1+r^2)\ c=1\\(1+r^2)\ s=r^2.$$
Then$$c-s=\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2}.$$